phpmyadmin database collation issue for utf8mb4
I am using phpmyadmin mysql version 8.0.31
Default Server Connection Collation in phpmyadmin of new server is shown = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
When I download mysql database from old server with mysql v 5.7.33 and upload it to this new server with mysql 8.0.31 via phpmyadmin, database tables from old server with collation utf8_unicode_ci are getting converted to utf8mb3_unicode_ci instead of utf8mb4_unicode_ci
and hence I am losing some text saved in columns and they are getting weird (hindi words not showing) when displayed via php echo statement.
Images attached below :
IMAGE 1 :

IMAGE 2 :


Please show us some text that has been mangled.  Your images show that things have been change from utf8mb3 to utf8mb4, but that that any data has been lost or mangled.

There is actually server collation setting too. Or why not just manually add charset/collation into your exported file at the table creating statements ?
